# SSRS Colour Expression Not Updating

Tags: reporting-services

I've added a colour expression to a dashboard but the colours are not updating. It's already using colour expressions on multiple values so I wonder if this could be the cause? The value is set at 0 and should be green, however, it's showing red still.

Tried deploying and deleting RDL cache file with no joy.

My expression:

```
=Iif((Sum(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Fields!STATUS_TYPE_ID.Value = 1 
AND IsNothing(Fields!ASSIGNED_TECH_ID.Value), 1, 0), "CallDetails")) <= 2
, "SeaGreen"
, Iif((Sum(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Fields!STATUS_TYPE_ID.Value = 1 
AND IsNothing(Fields!ASSIGNED_TECH_ID.Value), 1, 0), "CallDetails")) > 6
, "Red"
, "DarkOrange"
))
```

Expected result is for it to be green currently as the value is 0, however, the colour is currently a solid red.

Comment: @arahman I don't get what different seeing the data would do? All the current fields is doing is a sum of the number of unique ID's from a SQL query. I.e. getting the number 0, 1,2,3,4,5 and so on... yet the colour isn't changing for some reason. No nulls or anything are included in this query so I can't see where this expression could be going wrong. I've even put the query into a text box and its giving me the value 'Red' when it should be 'Green' because the expression value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is wrong. It think what you want is something like that:

1. Sum(x) <= 2  --> "SeaGreen"
2. Sum(x) >  6  --> "Red"
3. Else         --> "DarkOrange"

The expression would be then:

```
=IIF( 
      Sum( 
           IIF(Fields!STATUS_TYPE_ID.Value = 1 AND IsNothing(Fields!ASSIGNED_TECH_ID.Value), 1, 0),
          "CallDetails"
          ) <= 2, 
     "SeaGreen",
     IIF(
          Sum(
               IIF(Fields!STATUS_TYPE_ID.Value = 1 AND IsNothing(Fields!ASSIGNED_TECH_ID.Value), 1, 0),
              "CallDetails"
              ) > 6,
         "Red",
         "DarkOrange"
        )
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that also didn't work. The value is 4 and it's still showing as Red when it should be orange...? Any ideas..?! Even I change the green to <= 6, it still shows as red when it should be green.